# How to add a specific class to an input which has generated a form error?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I want to add a specific class to an input if an error is genereted by the input.

For example, if input is empty and has required validator it shouls look like this:

```
<dd id="login-element">
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="" class="input-text error" />
    <ul class="errors">
        <li>Value is required and can't be empty</li>
    </ul>
</dd>
```

class="input-text **error**"

Please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this tutorial to get a better understanding where to change your code: http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450-Decorators-with-Zend_Form

In your case, I would recommend either replacing the ViewHelper decorator with a decorator that creates the output you want. You can extend the `Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewHelper` class for this with your own code and overwrite the `getElementAttribs()` method to insert your class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with jquery! :)

I used the standard Decorators and manipulate the class of the preview Object in DOM.

```
$('ul.errors').prev().addClass("FieldError");
```

Comment: No offense to the poster and I applaud your creativity, but man. Zend framework SUCKS if this is what you have to resort to.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a Decorator, easy way to do this is set the class while you add the element in the `form` class. For example, you can use the following in the `init()` method of your `Zend_Form` class

```
$this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
    'label'      => 'Your email address:',
    'required'   => true,
    'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
    'validators' => array(
        'EmailAddress',
    ),
    'class' => 'input-large'
));
```